# PDFAnnotation not dragging when pdfview is zoom in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, pdf-annotations

I want to drag **PDFAnnotation** when the pdf view is zoomed in or zoomed out, I can drag Pin when the pdf is not zoomed in. Here is my code which is currently working.

```
import UIKit

import PDFKit



class ImageStampAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {
    
    var image: UIImage!
    
    // A custom init that sets the type to Stamp on default and assigns our Image variable
    init(with image: UIImage!, forBounds bounds: CGRect, withProperties properties: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        super.init(bounds: bounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.stamp, withProperties: properties)
        
        self.image = image
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
        
        // Get the CGImage of our image
        guard let cgImage = self.image.cgImage else { return }
        
        // Draw our CGImage in the context of our PDFAnnotation bounds
        context.draw(cgImage, in: self.bounds)
        
    }
}


class DragVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pdfContainerView: PDFView!
    
    var currentlySelectedAnnotation: PDFAnnotation?
    var signatureImage: UIImage?
    var annotations = [ImageStampAnnotation]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "PDF Viewer"
        self.signatureImage = UIImage(named: "Green-png")
        setupPdfView()
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        guard let signatureImage = signatureImage, let page = pdfContainerView.currentPage else { return }
        let pageBounds = page.bounds(for: .cropBox)
        let imageBounds = CGRect(x: pageBounds.midX, y: pageBounds.midY, width: 120, height: 120)
        let imageBounds1 = CGRect(x: pageBounds.midX + 100, y: pageBounds.midY + 100, width: 120, height: 120)
        let imageBounds2 = CGRect(x: pageBounds.midX + 150, y: pageBounds.midY + 150 , width: 120, height: 120)
        let imageStamp = ImageStampAnnotation(with: signatureImage, forBounds: imageBounds, withProperties: nil)
        imageStamp.fieldName = "1"
        let imageStamp1 = ImageStampAnnotation(with: signatureImage, forBounds: imageBounds1, withProperties: nil)
        imageStamp1.fieldName = "2"
        let imageStamp2 = ImageStampAnnotation(with: signatureImage, forBounds: imageBounds2, withProperties: nil)
        imageStamp2.fieldName = "3"
        
        page.addAnnotation(imageStamp)
        page.addAnnotation(imageStamp1)
        page.addAnnotation(imageStamp2)
        
        annotations.append(imageStamp)
        annotations.append(imageStamp1)
        annotations.append(imageStamp2)
    }
    
    func setupPdfView() {
        // Download simple pdf document
        if let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "example1", withExtension: "pdf"),
           let data = try? Data(contentsOf: documentURL),
           let document = PDFDocument(data: data) {
            
            // Set document to the view, center it, and set background color
            pdfContainerView.document = document
            pdfContainerView.autoScales = true
            pdfContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            
            let panAnnotationGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
            pdfContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(panAnnotationGesture)
            
            
        }
    }
    
    
    
    @objc func handlePanGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let touchLocation = sender.location(in: pdfContainerView)
        
        guard let page = pdfContainerView.page(for: touchLocation, nearest: true)
        else {
            return
        }
        let locationOnPage = pdfContainerView.convert(touchLocation, to: page)
        
        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            
            
            guard let annotation = page.annotation(at: locationOnPage) else {
                return
            }
            
            if annotation.isKind(of: ImageStampAnnotation.self) {
                currentlySelectedAnnotation = annotation
            }
            
        case .changed:
            
            guard let annotation = currentlySelectedAnnotation else {
                return
            }
            let initialBounds = annotation.bounds
            
            if let index = annotations.firstIndex(of: annotation as! ImageStampAnnotation) {
                annotations[index].bounds = CGRect(x: locationOnPage.x, y: locationOnPage.y , width: initialBounds.width, height: initialBounds.height)
            }
            
            let translation = sender.translation(in: self.pdfContainerView)
            let newPosition = CGPoint(x: annotation.bounds.origin.x + translation.x,
                                      y: annotation.bounds.origin.y + translation.y)
            annotation.bounds.origin = newPosition
            sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: self.pdfContainerView)
            
        case .ended, .cancelled, .failed:
            currentlySelectedAnnotation = nil
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    //
}
```